# How to Connect Virtual Machines in a Cloud Service using REST

Tags: rest, azure, hyperlink, virtual-machine, iaas

I'm working with Virtual Machines on Windows Azure and according to the following link: 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/connect-to-a-cloud-service/
it is possible to link various Virtual Machines to the same cloud service. The provided link clearly explains how to do it by means of the Windows Azure Management Portal. Nevertheless, in my case, I want to do the same using the REST API. Anyone knows how can it be done?

Thank you so much in advance,
Abel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to "add role" to add a new VM to an existing IaaS Cloud service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157186.aspx